How can I calculate the magnetic field of a plasma?
If I created a plasma and put a large electric current through it would a magnetic field be created? If so how large would this field be and how can I calculate it?
For example, we put 1000 amperes through the plasma with the plasma having a slightly lower resistance than the average copper wire.

First question and I don’t know much physics but I need to know for a project so please inform me on what I am doing wrong.

Magnetohydrodynamics. But ... it's complicated!

The magnetic field will vary with distance away from the source (i.e., the current-carrying particles) and it will depend upon the geometry of the current source (e.g., a line of current generates a different field than flat sheet of current).

Magnetic fields created by currents running in a plasma are no different than those created by currents carrying wire.
You need to know the current density in your plasma and then apply Ampere's law. Things get complicated because the current density depends on the applied electric field but also on the pressure of both ions and electrons in the plasma.
